# Existence and uniqueness of initial value problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

For existence and uniqueness of first order initial value problems on $\mathbb{R}^n$, theorems like Picard's theorem gives only local information.

I wonder when we can say an initial value problem $y'=f(x,y),y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ has unique solution on $(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$, for any given initial condition $y(a)=y_1\in\mathbb{R}$.

(The condition on $f$ can be specified as much as needed and inequalities can also be given, but let's not assume to be linear.)

Comment: It helps to have a global Lipschitz condition on $[a,b]\times \Bbb R$, or local Lipschitz and a linear bound on $f$, all wrt. $y$. Do you know about this?

Comment: If such condition is sufficient, it would be much interesting for me. I've perhaps heard of the first one, but second one never.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094871/existence-of-unique-global-solution/2094914#2094914 relates to the linear bound. It uses a globalish Lipschitz condition, but the principal idea applies also to general bounds $\|f(x,y)\|\le A+B\|y\|$.